# MYSQL Where on Date column returning duplicates

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue with a query on MYSQL
When I'm searching on a date column, "accountclosed", it's returning rather peculiar results and I'm trying to wrap my head around why

```
SELECT sdb2.ClientID, CONCAT(pdb.lastName, ',',' ', pdb.firstNames) AS Name,sdb2.AccNo,
SUM(IF(buyOrSell = "B", numOfShares,-1*numOfShares)) AS holding, 
IF(cacc.accountclose>'0000-00-00', "Closed", "Open") As AccountStatus       

FROM sharesdb2 sdb2
JOIN
ClientsDB cdb on sdb2.clientID=cdb.clientID
JOIN
peopledb pdb on sdb2.ClientID=pdb.clientID
JOIN clientaccounts cacc ON sdb2.clientID=cacc.clientID 

WHERE cdb.personortrust = 'p'
AND sdb2.transType != 'X'

GROUP BY sdb2.ClientID, sdb2.AccNo
```

Now, I would expect this to return each account and if it was "Open" or "Closed" based on the value in the "accountclose" Field. However, I am getting the below instead

```
ClientID AccNo     holding    AccountStatus accountclose
549      11506462  -4812.00   Closed        2019-10-29
549      11509530  -81924.00  Closed        2019-10-29
```

The table that the accountclose data is showing this:

```
clientID AccNo    accountOpen accountClose
549      11506462 2013-04-05  2019-10-29
549      11509530 2013-04-15  0000-00-00
```

I've been scratching my head for a while on this. Does anyone have any insight? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your actual expected output?

Comment: The expected output would be a match-up of the accountclose value and the accno. For some reason I'm unaware of, it's returning a single accountclose value for both cses of the clientID value

Comment: `JOIN clientaccounts cacc ON sdb2.clientID=cacc.clientID`  It seems you forget to join by `AccNo`...

Comment: Akina, that's fixed it. Silly oversight. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
JOIN
ClientsDB cdb on sdb2.clientID=cdb.clientID
```

and the next JOIN too should have

```
and a.AccNo= b.AccNo
```